# Use Custom debug key to debug android application?

Tags: android, debugging, google-maps, keystore

I have include Google map view in my android application. When I debug with my computer in office it gives the map in my map view. But when I try to test it at home it did not give any map.

I need to know how can I debug with custom debug key so I can test it with any computer other than my office computer.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each key is unique for specific computer. You have to generate a debug key for each computer you use.
Another solution is to register an account in market and get account's key. Using this key, you can run the application from each computer you want, but you have to export signed apk.

Comment: Actually, you can move debug keys between your own computers.